# virtual methods and template classes

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

I got over a problem, I think a very specific one.

I've got 2 classes, a **B** aseclass and a **D** erived class (from **B** aseclass).
**B** is a template class ( or class template) and has a *pure virtual method* `virtual void work(const T &dummy) = 0;`
The **D** erived class is supposed to reimplement this, but as **D** is Derived from **B**  rather than **D** being another template class, the compiler spits at me that virtual functions and templates don't work at once.

Any ideas how to accomplish what I want?

I am thankfull for any thoughts and Ideas, especially if you allready worked out that problem

this class is fixed aka AS IS, I can not edit this without breaking existing code base

```
template <typename T>
class B {
public:
...
virtual void work(const T &dummy) = 0;
..
};
```

take int* as an example

```
class D : public B<int*>{
...
virtual void work(const int* &dummy){ /* put work code here */ }
..
};
```

Edit: The compiler tells me, that `void B<T>::work(const T&)` `[with T = int*]` is *pure virtual* within **D**

Comment: Read here why it still does not work for me (as tried this with Qt classes), Qt design shortcoming... http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-02/thread00693-0.html

Comment: and see here http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq15-academic.html
in the end I have to use old evil void* instead of templates...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You placed the const in the wrong place. Try

```
virtual void work(int* const &dummy){ /* put work code here */ }
```

`const int*` is the same as `int const*`, i.e. it associates the const with the int and not the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int* const& dummy
```

Comment: Does this really matter, I mean I did it like above since I learned C++ and nobody complained so far... so far... Is there some documentation and best practice for const?

Comment: It's the difference between "const pointer to a int" and "a pointer to a const int"

Comment: Addition: `const` is binding to the left, unless to the left is nothing, then it binds to the right (which is the most common usage)

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler?

g++ 4.4 didn't complain about:

```
template <typename T>
class B {
public:
virtual void work(const T &dummy) = 0;
};
class D : public B<int*>{
virtual void work(const int* &dummy){ /* put work code here */ }
};

int main(){return 0;}
```

EDIT: Of course - the error only showed up when actually instantiating D, fixed by moving the const keyword:

```
template <typename T>
class B {
public:
virtual void work(const T &dummy) = 0;
};
class D : public B<int*>{
virtual void work(int* const &dummy){ /* put work code here */ }
};

int main(){D d;return 0;}
```

Comment: @Douglas Because you didn't use the templates.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mixture of const and reference problems. The  following compiles:

```
template <typename T>
struct B {
virtual void work(T dummy) = 0;
};

struct D : public B<int*>{
virtual void work( int* dummy){ /* put work code here */ }
};

int main() {
    D d;
    d.work( 0 );
}
```